# How to select common date from three tables in laravel?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-6.2

I have these three tables in my database  and I want to select the common date from three tables to calculate the profit of every day , profit of every month, and profit of every year

this is my tables :

```
Schema::create('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');            
    $table->string('name');
    $table->float('amount');
    $table->string('month');
    $table->string('year');
    $table->string('date');
});
```

```
Schema::create('service_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('client_id')->unsigned();
    $table->double('total_price', 8, 2)->nullable();
    $table->string('month');
    $table->string('year');
    $table->date('date');
    $table
        ->foreign('client_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('clients')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('client_id')->unsigned();
    $table->double('total_price', 8, 2)->nullable();
    $table->string('month');
    $table->string('year');
    $table->date('date');
    $table
        ->foreign('client_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('clients')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: try your self using `join` queries - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

Comment: I will suggest you, get 3 different data with whatever your date you want. after that, calculate by php. it will be eaiser for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem can be solved by UNIONS

UNION used to combine the result of two or more tables

```
  SELECT date FROM expenses
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date FROM service_orders
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date FROM orders
```

To use it in Laravel you can check documentation below:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions